# Selection/Extraction of features based on location AND attribute

Tags: qgis, select-by-location

My data consists of a point layer (iceberg positions containing their acquisition date as attributes) and a polygon layer (areal extends of DEMs also containing the acquisition date).

My aim is to select/extract the features based on their same location (the iceberg positions overlapping with the DEM extends) AND under the condition that they possess the same acquisition date.

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how I can solve this problem.
What I tried is:

1. Extracting by location, which only fulfills the condition that their locations overlap
2. To figure out how to run an extraction/selection based on the attributes of different layers, which I haven't figured out yet

[image: Both the layers of the iceberg positions and DEM extends extracted by their (intersecting/overlapping) location. I try to figure out how to extract/select those, who intersect AND have the same acquisition date]

Answer (score 6):

You can use a virtual layer to join the layers. You can then `save as` the output if you want to persist the data.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Replace the layer name for yours

```sql
select pt.*, poly.ID
from mypointlayer pt
join mypolygonlayer poly
 on st_intersects(pt.geometry, poly.geometry)
    AND pt.acquisition_date = poly.acquisition_date
```

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve your request using the tool *Select feature by expression* available in the selection Toolbar. [image]

Here, having the point layer active in the TOC, you can use this expression

```
contains(
aggregate(
layer:='polygon',
aggregate:='collect',
expression:=$geometry,
filter:="date" = '2020-09-06'
)
,$geometry)
```

This will select all the points that are inside the polygons that respect the filter rule: in this case only the polygons that have a specific data as attribute.

[image]

Having all the requested point selected you can now create a new layer exporting only the selected features.